# Firebase database equalto query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database in firebase :

```
sessions
 -LPzeTZznhX6C69xLIP-
  code: 68173
  players
   0: -LPzi4NtLF28Jxfb_H_A

 -LQ3AeckOaiTR3JuHgAn
  code: 76417
  players
   0: -LPzi4NuUhm_jhAWZYTH
```

I want to insert a player in 'players' where 
code(given by me) is equal to code(in database) 
what should the query for this ?

```
firebase.database().ref('sessions/').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val().code); 
firebase.database().ref("sessions/"+ snapshot.key ).orderByChild("code").queryEqual(code).child("players").push(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
});
```

I have tried this query, but it inserts player at every players array.

Comment: Are you sure your provided database structure is correct? I see `code` and `players` two times inside the same `session` which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: oh so sorry every code and player is under a unique id ,its like the array of sessions